# In Visual Studio Online, when I add a new State, can I also add the new state's specific "Changed Date" as a column in queries?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

When I view the Backlog in Visual Studio, I can add a Column, and there are Date-related columns like "Closed Date" and "Resolved Date" related to States Closed and Resolved. If I add my own States (which I have), can I also get Date columns for when a ticket exited those states?

Because I want to show a Query that includes the date of all of those states (to easily track when each ticket exited those states.

So if I add a State called "Spec Approved", then I also want a "Spec Approved Date" column added. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can add the `"Spec Approved Date"` column, just add a new filed with the name `"Spec Approved Date"`.

Actually in your scenario you can use the existing field `State Change Date` to reflect the time when change state to "`Spec Approved`".

**Refer below steps to achieve that:** (See [Add a custom field in VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/process/customize-process-field?toc=/vsts/work/customize/toc.json&bc=/vsts/work/customize/breadcrumb/toc.json#add-a-custom-field))

1. Add a new state "`Spec Approved`"
2. Add a new field, add `"Spec Approved Date"` field for example.  (Actually you can use the existing `State Change Date` field in your scenario.)
3. Add rules to specify the value/behavior of the field.
4. Change the workitem state to "`Spec Approved`" to check the if the
   added field works or not.
5. New a query with the added field as the filter.
6. Edit the Column options to display the columns you needed in the
   query result.

You can also reference this article : [How to add custom fields to existing work items for VSTS](http://mohamedradwan.com/2016/07/05/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-existing-work-items/)

[image]